# Issue about the Numpy shape

Tags: python, numpy

There are .npy, with the shape, (37, 3, 224, 224). These are images, which resides in 'E:/augmentTest' folder. There are 1384 such .npy files in the folder.

I read these files and loaded in to numpy array.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET/resnet_50/dbs2017/data/stage1_labels.csv')

x = np.array([np.mean(np.load('E:/augmentTest/%s.npy' % str(id)), axis=0) for 
id in df['id'].tolist()])

print (x.shape)
```

When print the shape of the x , I got the following results.

```
(1384, 3, 224, 224).
```

I'm wondering how the shape of x has become 4D. Because x contains .npy files with shape, (37, 3, 224, 224), (67, 3, 224, 224), (50, 3, 224, 224) etc. Has the real shape of images changed when it put to arrray x?

Shape (1384, 3, 224, 224) means that it has 1384 images with (3,224,224). But my real images are with shape (37, 3, 224, 224), (67, 3, 224, 224), (50, 3, 224, 224). So I feel that the first dimension of the images has missed when it is put to x? Have I missed something here? Can someone please help meto understand this?

Comment: They are colour images, so the second dimension `3` indicates the RGB channels.

Comment: `np.mean(np.load('E:/augmentTest/%s.npy' % str(id)), axis=0)` You've calculated the mean across each one of your loaded images on the first axis, thus collapsing the dimensions into `3, 224, 224`, and loaded `1384` images. Therefore, your final array is of size `1384, 3, 224, 224`.

Comment: Oh I have missed it. Thanks for answering :) Please put it as as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is size `1384, 3, 224, 224` because of this command:

`np.mean(np.load('E:/augmentTest/%s.npy' % str(id)), axis=0)`

After loading, each of the images are `mean`ed in across its first dimension, collapsing the array into size `3, 224, 224`. Since `1384` images are loaded and `mean`ed, your final array is of size `1384, 3, 224, 224`.